# .map() function on Jquery array confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, map-function

I am trying to achieve something very simple but can't quite get it to work properly.

I am looping through the `td` children of a `tr` and trying to get the values of the cell into an array.

`$($("#thetable").find("tr")[0]).find("td").map(function(x) {return $(x).innerText;});`

What am I doing wrong ?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chapo/xpvt214o/896230/) if that helps.

Comment: What is the HTML?

Comment: Added jsfiddle link

Comment: `x` is the index of the element. Use `$(this).text()`, and also don't forget to call `get()` after `map()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, with jQuery array-like methods, the first argument is the *index*, not the element in question. Another problem is that `innerText` is a property of a *plain element*, not a jQuery collection - either use the jQuery version (`.text()`), or don't convert the element to a jQuery collection first:

```js
var rows = $("#thetable").find("tr")
var test = $(rows[0]).find("td").map(function(_, x) { return x.innerText;});
console.log(test);
```

```html
  <table id="thetable">
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Of course, using `.map` on a jQuery collection will give you a jQuery collection in return - if you don't want that, either call `.get()` on the result to convert it to an array

```
var test = $(rows[0]).find("td").map(function(_, x) { return x.innerText;}).get();
```

or simply use a native array method in the first place, rather than jQuery (there's no need for jQuery for something this simple anyway):

```js
const arr = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('#thetable td'),
  td => td.textContent
);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <table id="thetable">
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: still need to use `.get()` at the end.

Comment: thks for the torough and lightning-speed explanation - will validate the answer when I can

Answer (score 0):

The `x` value stores the index of the element found not the element, use `this` to get the current element and `text()` to get the inner text:

```
var rows = $("#thetable").find("tr")
console.log($(rows[0]).find("td"));
var test = $(rows[0]).find("td").map(function(x) {return $(this).text();});
console.log(test);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hL2g7w/)

To transfrom the jquery object in a plain array use the `get()` method

```
console.log(test.get());
```